# If transubstantiation is true, did Jesus eat some of His own body and drink some of His own blood?

Tags: communion, gospels, transubstantiation

Jesus sent disciples to prepare a place so He could eat the Passover with them. (Luke 22:8).  He did eat with them at this meal (Mark 14:18).  I could not find any indication that after having blessed and broken the bread and, declaring that is was his body and distributing it to the disciples, Jesus Himself ate some of it.  Since this was a repurposing of the Passover, which Jesus expressed eagerness to eat with them, it seems at least possible that He did partake.

There is some more direct indication, however, that He did partake of the wine:

> Verily I say unto you, I will drink no more of the fruit of the vine, until that day that I drink it new in the kingdom of God. - Mark 14:25.

My questions are for those who hold to the doctrine of transubstantiation:  1) Did Jesus partake of the elements of this first Lord's Supper and, if so, 2) Did He eat His own flesh and drink His own blood?

Comment: The real question is : if a man eats his own flesh, does his weight gets reduced?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does transubstantiation apply to the Last Supper, which occurred prior to the crucifixion?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8956/does-transubstantiation-apply-to-the-last-supper-which-occurred-prior-to-the-cr)

Comment: @Kris It does help, as is shown by the inclusion of this link in ABMK's  answer, but it's not an answer in and of itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I refer to this question and answers: [Does transubstantiation apply to the Last Supper, which occurred prior to the crucifixion?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8956/does-transubstantiation-apply-to-the-last-supper-which-occurred-prior-to-the-cr)

If transubstantiation occurred at the last supper, and it is to be expected that Christ ate and drank, and the Holy Scriptures don't teach that He didn’t, then it is fair to assume He did eat and drink His own body and blood.